# Vim 8.2 no user defined functions

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions, vim8

Yesterday I updated Vim to version 8.2 thru my Linux distro repositories (Fedora). And now I noticed that no user defined functions exist. They worked just yesterday, before the update.

I define several functions in my vimrc file. It used to work, but now it looks like definition rules have changed or something like that:

```
function! Foo()
  echo 'foo'
endfunction
echo exists('Foo')
```

This outputs `0`.

This is the output of `$: vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 16 2021 00:00:00)
Included patches: 1-3354
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sodium            -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim82"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lselinux -lncurses -lsodium -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
```

Could anyone, please, explain what happened?

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble on the other hand images have some benefits. They are rather precise (provided the resolution is sufficient), you cannot make a typo, they give a better context from where they came from.

Comment: You can’t typo copy and paste either (for example, `vim --version | pbcopy` on a mac). They serve to illustrate graphical problems well, but for textual matters they are simply the wrong medium. I lay out a few reasons in my post: even good resolution does not combat some problems (for example, small screen of a phone). Not sure what context is relevant for the text that you would want an image in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a regression bug in [8.2.3337](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8765) and it was [fixed](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/5aec755b678cfd434b8ea2158d06992f33e1ff80) [yesterday](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/8774).

Comment: I thought it was a plugin's fault. Since functions exist, if I start Vim thru `vim --noplugin`

Comment: Plugins you use most probably have `dict` functions. I had the same issue, removing single plugin made it work, which was very confusing.

Comment: I installed Vim 9 on several machines to get around this bug, but I am STILL getting warnings about unknown functions that work fine on other Ubuntu 22.04 machines. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I dunno what.

Answer (score 2):

To test whether a function exists, you should check `*funcname` (with a "star") prefix. So this will work:

```
:echo exists('*Foo')
1
```

Checking a name without the "star" prefix will actually check whether a variable by that name exists:

```
:let Bar = 99
:echo exists('Bar')
1
```

See `:help exists()`.